# miglayout and getting actual size of a swing component

Tags: java, miglayout

I have to show a jpg image in a `JLabel` maximizing the dimension and maintaining the proportion.
No problem using an absolute layout: I use `getWidth` and `getHeigth` of jlabel and resize and center the image.
But using miglayout, the two functions return a zero value.
I use Eclipse and WindowBuilder.

Comment: *I use WindowBuilder.* My condolences.  You can't get the actual width or height of a component until you've executed the JFrame pack or setSize method.

Comment: Very tanks Gilbert: pack solved the problem!